# Excluding some columns in the attribute table for the public use

Tags: data, attribute-table, arcgis-online, feature-service

I am trying to post a feature service for an Open Data Hub site but want to exclude some columns in the attribute table for the public use.

Is there a way to use a feature service but alternate the attribute table to exclude information such as 'moduser' 'moddate' or 'idnumber'?

These are things that we don't want the public to see, but want to be publishing our data to our open data hub site. Without creating a new service, is there a way to edit the attribute table without deleting it from the original source?

**Note**: Hiding columns does not work for when the dataset is being downloaded by a public user.

Comment: Possible as Owner or admin but note:You cannot delete system fields such as the OBJECTID, CREATIONDATE, CREATOR, EDITDATE, and EDITOR fields or fields used for styling, the time slider, filter, labels, search, or editor tracking. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/add-or-delete-fields.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have created a work around with this issue. I think it will be beneficial to others trying to establish an open data site through hub. In Model Builder I have brought in each feature class that I plan to put on our Open Data Site. Each layer I have ran 'feature class to feature class' and created a new FGDB that this will populate. The model will also delete the previous and replace with the new, as I plan to keep this updated monthly.